# Angular Virtual Scroll Jumps around

Tags: angular, angular-material, scrollview, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I am using Angular Material Virtual scroll, the items get loaded correctly into the DOM, but while scrolling it happens that it jumps around and automatically jumps to the end.

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport #scrollViewport  (scrolledIndexChange)="scrolled($event)" [itemSize]="ITEM_SIZE"  class="my-virtual" >
    <div *cdkVirtualFor="let elem of elemtArray;" class="input-field-container ">

        <div class="my-style" >{{elem}} </div>

    </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

The output of the method scrolled is the following, if the glitch occurs:

```
Scrolled:  105
Scrolled:  115
Scrolled:  106
Scrolled:  117
Scrolled:  109
Scrolled:  119
Scrolled:  110
Scrolled:  121
```

If this happens, it automatically scrolls to the end of the virtual scroll.

Comment: In my case, Scroll was rendering new items, then suddenly removing them, and scrolling back to the top of the list.
I couldn't find the reason, but adding a `trackByFn` to `cdkVirtualFor` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual scroll relies on an calculatable element height to calculate the offsets. To control this, set the input `itemSize` of `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` to whatever height you expect your items to have (in px).

if your ITEM_SIZE does not match the actual item size, then your described behavior will happen.

example:

css:

```
.my-style {
    height: 42px;
}
```

html:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="42" [...]>
     <!-- ... --->
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, my Problem was that i used some special kind of styling inside my virtual scroll

Comment: @Elrond What was your styling? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Elrond can you tell us what was causing that behavior?